# E/LB (26008): fail to open file: No such file or directory -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to get a List from this Api(https://www.getpostman.com/collections/fa1296508e65891de558)

But there does no appear any Object. Console showing => "E/LB      (26008): fail to open file: No such file or directory

".

I tried to print respone.statusCode but the result does'n apper in console.
I hope to solve this problem, Thank you.

What can be the problem here?

My code:

```
class ApiSetting{
  static const String _baseUri='http://demo-api.mr-dev.tech/api/';
  static const String users= '${_baseUri}users';
}
    

**User Model
**    class User {
  late int id;
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String email;
  late String mobile;
  late String bio;
  late String jobTitle;
  late String latitude;
  late String longitude;
  late String country;
  late String image;
  late String active;
  late String emailVerifiedAt;
  late String imagesCount;

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    email = json['email'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    jobTitle = json['job_title'];
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
    country = json['country'];
    image = json['image'];
    active = json['active'];
    emailVerifiedAt = json['email_verified_at'];
    imagesCount = json['images_count'];
  }
}


    
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:api_secand_project/api/api_setting.dart';
import 'package:api_secand_project/models/user.dart';


class UserApiController {
  Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(ApiSetting.users);
    var response = await http.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var userJsonArray = jsonResponse['data'] as List;
      return userJsonArray
          .map((jsonObject) => User.fromJson(jsonObject))
          .toList();
    }
    return [];
  }
}



    import 'package:api_secand_project/api/controllers/user_api_controller.dart';
import 'package:api_secand_project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UsersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UsersScreen> createState() => _UsersScreenState();
}

class _UsersScreenState extends State<UsersScreen> {

  List<User> _users=<User>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Users'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: UserApiController().getUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            else if(snapshot.hasData){
              _users=snapshot.data!;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _users.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      // child: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.),
                    ),
                    title: Text(_users[index].firstName),
                    subtitle: Text(_users[index].mobile),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(child: Text('No Data',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 28),),);
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was not very clear, and there is no clear screenshot or message from the error console,

It seems that you are using the BLOC pattern and since part of the code is missing, you decide to create one from scratch, maybe it will help you, I thought not to publish it, but maybe something from here will help you

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GetApi extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetApi({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetApi> createState() => _GetApiState();
}

class _GetApiState extends State<GetApi> {
  List<User> users = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Get Api")),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              getApi();
            },
            child: const Text("Get Api"),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: users.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  User user = users[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.name),
                    subtitle: Text(user.id),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getApi() async {
    users = [];
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.getpostman.com/collections/fa1296508e65891de558 ");
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //debugPrint("body: ${response.body}");
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (MapEntry item in data.entries) {
        //debugPrint("key: ${item.key} value: ${item.value}");
        if ("item" == item.key) {
          List usersResponse = data["item"];
          //debugPrint("users: ${users}");
          for (dynamic json in usersResponse) {
            User user = User.fromJson(json);
            users.add(user);
            //debugPrint("user: ${_user.name}");
          }
        }
      }

      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {});
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("succes -> status: ${response.statusCode}"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      if (!mounted) return;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("fail -> status: ${response.statusCode}"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

class User {
  late String name;
  late String id;

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    id = json['id'];
  }
}
```